# which file is responsible for display product on home page in virtuemart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Please tell me that which file is display products on index.php in virtuemart.

which file is responsible for display product on home page in virtuemart
Thanks in advance!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**shopIndex.tpl.php**(File path :- components\com_virtuemart\themes\default\templates\common) file is responsible for virtuemarat product

Answer (score 0):

Look in components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/browse for your product list pages and components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/product_details for your product detail page.

Which actual file you need is dependent on which browse and detail pages are specified in your VM configuration.